# Milnor's book notation (smooth structure) and its up to date

Tags: notation, differential-topology

What exactly is the notation of smooth structure in Milnor's book and how to pronounce it? What is its up to date (equivalence) notation?

[image]

Comment: it looks like a cursive S

Comment: Seems to be a typeset S. Not sure if there is a standard notation.

Comment: It is $\mathcal{S}$, pronounced "S".

Comment: As the others have said it is a fancy "S". If you are on a blackboard and want to verbally distinguish this S from a normal S you would say something like "script S", "curly S", "fancy S" etc. (Side comment, it also looks like a mirrored ampersand: "&")

Comment: Ok. Thanks to all. I wanna to proceed my oldbookstonew project https://mathoverflow.net/q/318839/90655 and I was doubt about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

The smoothness structure is certainly denoted by some version of an "S". See the comments, especially that of  s.harp. It is pronounced as "S".

Since the letter is handwritten, it does not make sense to associate a definite font as available in Latex or MathJax.